# Stackdriver Trace and Firebase Cloud Functions: "Tracing might not work"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

I'm trying to setup Stackdriver Trace with Firebase Cloud Functions.

But I'm getting errors, even when `@google-cloud/trace-agent` is the first module loaded:

```
ERROR:@google-cloud/trace-agent: TraceAgent#start: Tracing might not work as the following modules were loaded before the trace agent was initialized: [accepts, body-parser, bytes, content-disposition, content-type, cookie, cookie-signature, crc, debug, depd, destroy, ee-first, escape-html, etag, express, finalhandler, forwarded, fresh, iconv-lite, ipaddr.js, media-typer, merge-descriptors, methods, mime, mime-db, mime-types, ms, negotiator, on-finished, parseurl, path-to-regexp, proxy-addr, qs, range-parser, raw-body, send, serve-static, type-is, utils-merge, vary]
```

It seems related to module loaded by Firebase itself.

Is there a solution to prevent this log from showing or what is the best way to make Trace work with Firebase Cloud Functions ?